# Do the columns of the given matrix span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: matrices, span

I was given the matrix:

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}-4 & -7 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 8\\5 & -1 &1 & -4\end{matrix}\right)$$

I arranged them into an augmented matrix and added a 5th column of zeroes. I row reduced until I got

$$B=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 &1 & 8 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$

I let $t$ denote a free variable: $x2=0, x3=-8, x1=2, x4=t$.

I know that the pivot columns must stay in the matrix. I also know that if the amount of vectors is greater than or equal to the span we are still unsure if the vectors are in the given span.

I want to know if I am on the right track and what step I should take next. Can I take out the 4th column and row reduce again to verify that the leftover vectors are in the span?

Comment: I haven't grasped all of the formatting techniques, so I apologize.

Comment: This reference is a very useful introduction: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I edited the matrices, but I don't really understand what you mean after you introduce $t$.

Comment: Thanks Travis! 
So when I go to solve I got the x_2 =0
x_{3} =-8  x_{1} =2  x_{4} =t      t is a free variable that I chose to denote that x_{4} is not a pivot column.

Comment: Why did u add that 5th column????

Comment: @Allison Did Crawshaw or I answer your question?  If so, you should hit the checkmark left of one of our answers (it'll turn green once you do).  Otherwise, what should I elaborate on?

Comment: @bye_world almost, not quite, I added more to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an augmented matrix in this case.

Starting with $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}-4 & -7 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 8\\5 & -1 &1 & -4\end{matrix}\right)$$ just row reduce like you did.  I'll assume you're correct and that the RREF of this matrix is $$\operatorname{RREF}(A)=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -2\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 &1 & 8\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then you just count the pivots:

$$\require{enclose}\left(\begin{matrix}\enclose{circle}{1} & 0 & 0 & -2\\
0 & \enclose{circle}{1} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 &\enclose{circle}{1} & 8\end{matrix}\right)$$

There are $3$ pivots in this case, meaning the row rank is $3$.  By the theorem which tells us the row rank = the column rank of a matrix, we also know that the column rank of $A$ is $3$.  Thus there are $3$ linearly independent columns of $A$.

$\Bbb R^3$ has a dimension of $3$ (can you prove this?), thus *any* $3$ linearly independent vectors will span it.  Thus the columns of $A$ do indeed span $\Bbb R^3$.

---

**Appendix: Theorems needed for the above**

1. Row reduction (by elementary row operations) preserves the row space of a matrix
2. The number of pivots of a matrix in RREF equals the row rank of a matrix.
3. The row rank = the column rank of a matrix (and thus you can just refer to it as **the** rank of the matrix).
4. The dimension of a vector space $V$ is well-defined.  I.e. if the dimension of $V$ is $n$, then $(1)$ any $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n \in V$ is a spanning set, $(2)$ any set of less than $n$ vectors will NOT be a spanning set, and $(3)$ any set of more than $n$ vectors will necessarily be linearly dependent. (So this one is really $3$ different theorems.)

If you haven't encountered one or more of these theorems, you may have to do the problem a different way (or prove these theorems yourself). ;)

Comment: So you're saying that because the three columns are linearly independent and there are three, and not less, that they span {R}^3? If there were more columns and the fourth column was not linearly independent would the set still span? Also in this case, or any similar case why would i not need to add a row of zeroes when row reducing?

Comment: And thank you for answering my question, other than my additional question you were very clear!

Comment: Yes.  Any three linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ will span $\Bbb R^3$.  You actually have $4$ columns here, so all four don't form a linearly independent set, but any three of them do and that means that all four form a spanning set.  In fact you could just keep adding columns all day to this and it'd still form a spanning set because the *first three columns by themselves* span $\Bbb R^3$.  The rest are just extra. You could add a column of zeros at the end if you wanted. But why bother? A column of zeros will stay a column of zeros under *any* elementary row operations.

Comment: Those additional columns would not be linearly independent though right? Just the first three?

Comment: I'm just trying to be clear :)

Comment: Technically vectors themselves are never linearly (in)dependent, only *sets* of vectors.  Of your four column vectors, any three of them form a linearly independent set.  All four of them do not.  And if you added more columns, you might be able to take some a make a set of three that's *not* linearly independent, but you could never get a set of more than three linearly independent vectors because $\Bbb R^3$ is $3$-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps changing the format makes it easier to see. The given matrix provides you with 4 vectors with 3 components each. Thus this matrix can also be seen as

$\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 0 & 5 \\-7 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 2 & 8 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$

You can row reduce this matrix and find that it equals

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -(5/4) \\0 & 1 & (3/4) \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$
In this format it is clear that of the 4 given vectors, 3 are linearly independent with one linearly dependent and thus it indeed spans the vector space.